# Touched Point in iOS

Tags: ios

I have written the following code snippet.When user taps two times on the image(gesturerecognizer), it adds annotation. It adds an annotation successfully but it is not exactly where user tapps. There are some offset between the tapped point and annotation image location.

I could not able to figure that out so far. Most likely, I am missing a detail information which I am not aware of as of now. I am using ipad 2 simulator on landscape layout.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.imvPhoto addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
}
 - (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
        // handling code

        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
        NSLog(@"Coordinates are %f, %f", point.x, point.y);
        UIImage* anno=[UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation_icon.png"];

        imvPhoto.image = [self drawImage:anno inImage:imvPhoto.image atPoint:point];

    }
}

-(UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage*) fgImage
              inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage
              atPoint:(CGPoint)  point
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bgImage.size, FALSE, 0.0);
    [bgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, bgImage.size.width, bgImage.size.height)];
    [fgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake((point.x - fgImage.size.width/2), (point.y - fgImage.size.height/2), fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to add the sender's x and y to get the coordinates for the parent view? `locationInView:` returns the point in the coordinates of the sender view.

Comment: @Marcus,I am sending the "point" as a parameter to drawImage method. Is that what you point out

Comment: I think screen shots would help here. It is likely your `point` is relative to the wrong view.

Comment: I have got the answer and added here. Thanks a lot Marcus and picciano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is my background image size was 832 by 603, which I was not aware of. Once image is loaded, it was scaling up to full screen and I was thinking it is 1024*768. Once I fix the size of the image, then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the below code:

```
[fgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height)];
```

to

```
[fgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake((point.x - fgImage.size.width/2), (point.y - fgImage.size.height/2), fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height)];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tested with the same code. My image size 40*40, there is a offset more than 100. see updated code

Comment: Midhun, Please see my answer, I have got the problem. It was my mistake!

Comment: @casillas: Oh, yeah. I saw that. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Thanks for attempting to solve my problem. I have upvoted for your effort.